# Bicycle Uphill vs. Walking Uphill

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, biophysics

When bicycling uphill, I have noticed it takes a enormous amount of effort compared to just walking uphill. However, when on level ground, bicycling seems to take considerably less effort than walking. Also when bicycling uphill, I have noticed that turning the wheel lessens the effort required to keep the bicycle from continuing to move.

- Why does walking seemingly take less energy than bicycling uphill?
- Why does turning on a bicycle lessen the effort required to continue up the hill?

Comment: When you perform the experiment, do you control the speed? Are you certain that when you cycle up the hill, you aren't going any faster than you go when you walk?

Comment: "Why does turning on a bicycle lessen the effort required to continue up the hill?" For the same reason that most paths and roads up steep mountain sides zig-zag from side to side as they go up, to reduce the gradient at the cost of increased distance.

Comment: The bike has a weight between 15-30 lbs. Going up an incline requires carrying the extra weight of the bike. If you walked up the hill carrying the bike, then the comparison would be better.

Comment: You could use a calorie counter to get a rough estimate. Time yourself cycling up the hill then give yourself the same time to walk / run up it while carrying the bike.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier in a low gear.

When you walk, your foot moves about a foot, and presses your body + bike upward perhaps an inch.

When you ride a bike in high gear, you press your foot about a foot to turn the crank half a turn. This propels you and your bike forward perhaps a couple dozen feet, raising you perhaps a couple dozen inches.

If these made up numbers are true, then you can see you would have to press twice as hard on the bike. Note that during part of the turn your foot is near the top or bottom, where you are not pushing perpendicular to the crank. This part of the turn is even harder.